# What is writing a record to my access table?

Tags: ms-access

I am troubleshooting a form that I am creating. I had noticed that some records were erroneously being written in one of my tables each time the form was opened (which also had a lot of sub forms). I looked through the OnCurrent methods and didn't see anything. So I started adding some breakpoints to see if I could narrow it down. This is where it gets strange. If I remove the breakpoints, sure enough, the record gets written as I described. But if I add the breakpoints, and click on through each one SLOWLY (like wait a few seconds on each breakpoint), the record does not get written. But if I click through quickly, the record does get written, just as it did when I did not have the breakpoints at all.

So my question is, what kinds of things can cause access to do one thing when no breakpoints are enabled, and a different thing simply by adding in breakpoints and clicking through slowly?

Answer (score 1):

without going through it with a fine comb (which sounds like you already did), it could be a million things.  One of the forms could have code in it to insert the record when it opens or closes.  Could be a timer loop (to add a delay to inserting the record, perhaps), and someone forgot to close/stop the loop.
There could also be a module or a trigger-like (triggers from SQL Server), that get called when a field is accessed.
Again, without seeing the database or any code, it's hard to say.